# Better understanding 2FA

Tags: privacy, date-time, two-factor-authentication

Why does 2FA fail unless geo-location is enabled system wide ?

Solutions offered ( https://debiankalilinuxtips.substack.com/p/automatic-datetime-sync ) for date/time sync do not resolve 2fa requiring geo-location sync system wide.

Currently the only solution found is turn on geo-location system wide -> allow system to sync -> turn geo-location off -> proceed to visiting websites and using 2FA.

It is not an issue of vpn or tunnels.  The system synced to the geo-location time of the vpn/vps exit node and 2fa was happy with that geo-location.  4hr time difference between physical system location and synced vpn virtual location.  If vpn was the cause of 2fa system sync requirements then the 4hr difference would have prevented 2fa from working.

Can someone explain on a base level why system wide  geo-location sync is necessary and if it can be cli spoofed to allow 2fa to be happy but without exposing the entire system to geo-location.

all of the "white papers" about 2fa explain it works by a formula that adds current time to a predefined seed which generates a unique 6 digit code that is only true for a short period of time. this does not explain what system details are necessary.  Please explain why necessary / how to pass 2fa the region timezone rather than it checking local system details.

> $ timedatectl

```
              Local time: Fri 2022-01-28 07:41:04 MST
           Universal time: Fri 2022-01-28 14:41:04 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2022-01-28 14:41:04
                Time zone: America/Phoenix (MST, -0700)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're referencing as far as "geo-location system wide".  Can you share the steps you follow to change this setting?  My understanding is that for time-based one-time pad based 2FA (TOTP), the time zone does not matter, but the clock MUST be accurate to within no more than a minute or possibly less.  There are many 2FA options that are not time based; can you clarify what 2FA you are using?

Comment: geo-location system wide settings: on debian 9 or 10 -> settings -> Location Services.  Settings -> Date&Time "Automatic Time Zone - Requires location services enabled".  Automatic Time zone and Location services must be enabled for system clock sync to time zone for google2fa to work. (or any 2FA options based on the same formula, ie. authy, github authenticators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

So the 2FA tools you're referencing, including Google Authenticator, use TOTP.  This is a (T)ime-based (O)ne-(T)ime (P)assword.

It works by sharing a key or "secret" between your computer and the server once, when the TOTP is set up (that is what the QR code is about).  Both sides then execute an algorithm that is based on the current time and that secret in such a way that:

- Even if someone sees the output (the info you type into the 2FA prompt), they won't be able to predict the next one.
- The output changes with the time, often once or twice per minute (this is why you get a different set of numbers to type each time.

Because the server and your computer are working separately, to get the same answer they have to be using the same baseline information, which means the same secret (key), and the same time.  Generally speaking, we are all on the same page as what time it is, even if we use different numbers (24 hour vs 12 hour with AM/PM) and different time zones.  The TOTP calculations use the number of seconds since midnight on January 1st, 1970 in the UTC time zone. (see this documentation here, section 4.2: [https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-mraihi-totp-timebased-08.html#rfc.section.4])

Now, the automatic time-setting features you are referencing, either the systemd timesyncd feature or NTP, are going to be sufficient for setting the time accurately enough to use TOTP.  Any selection of time zone is irrelevant, be it automatic or manual (unless you change what time it is when you change the time zone, rather than letting the computer update the clock)

If you are willing to take the patience to set your computer clock to within a few seconds, and if it maintains accurate time pretty well, you can probably get away without automatic time synchronization and still have TOTP work, but in that case you need to be careful about the time zone you select as well (so that the computer knows the number of seconds since midnight UTC on January 1st, 1970), and you may need to make sure the clock is kept accurate manually (just as you would need to manually change a wall clock that is slow or fast)

Note that you don't have to use **your** time zone, but you have to make sure the time you set is accurate **now**, in the time zone you set.

Comment: your explanation makes sense, how to check if  systemd timesyncd accurately enough set the time to use TOTP.  I edited question and added timedatectl output.  In the wild it looks like UTC and RTC identical in sync, and Local Time spot on for timezone.  But OTP seems to not agree.

Comment: accepting your answer because your input helped clarify problem.  OTP and system time sync / RTC not why geolocation is necessary for OTP.  Your answer verified timedatectl is setup so OTP "should" work, leaving the only possibility a problem with system time sync vs. what OTP expects.